# Google account get Token

Tags: android, google-api-client

I have a problem with kitkat api while tringy to get access token of google account services, google music in my case. So, if user trying get token at first by using next method:

```
 public String getAuthToken(Account account)
            throws AuthenticatorException, IOException {
        String s1;
        if (account == null) {
            Log.e("MusicAuthInfo", "Given null account to MusicAuthInfo.getAuthToken()", new Throwable());
            throw new AuthenticatorException("Given null account to MusicAuthInfo.getAuthToken()");
        }
        String s = getAuthTokenType(mContext);
        try {
            s1 = AccountManager.get(mContext).blockingGetAuthToken(account, s, true);
        } catch (OperationCanceledException operationcanceledexception) {
            throw new AuthenticatorException(operationcanceledexception);
        }
        if (s1 == null) {
            throw new AuthenticatorException("Received null auth token.");
        }

        return s1;
    }
```

here i get `s1 == null` and the system push notification:

[image: notification]

When user tap on notification, next dialog appear:

[image: dialog]

When user click "ok", all next iterations getting token get success.

**Question:** How to circumvent this confirmation or show just dialog, without click to notification ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but you can use Google Play Services instead.

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, userEmail, "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/");
```

You just have to specify the oauth2 scope you need. For instance for Google+ you would need "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" instead of what I post in the snippet for Gmail. You can also specify multiple scopes in one token request. The permission request pops up right away.

You can read all about it here: [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html), [Login scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes)

Comment: Well, to get a scope for a token you first need to have an idea which API do you look a scope for. Among the available APIs there's no Google Play Music one specifically. You can check all of them here: [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and you need to make sure the API is enabled in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). Check which API gives you the privileges you need. For instance the Google+ one might include these.

Answer (score -3):

Solved. Need use this method:

```
Bundle result = AccountManager.get(activity).getAuthToken(account, s, new Bundle(), activity, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
        try {
            Log.e("xxx", future.getResult().toString());
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}, null).getResult();
```